# "Spoil" vs "Ruin"

Tags: word-usage, word-difference, american-english

My question is,

Can you spoil a moment? for example, let's say I bring home a gift for my girlfriend and she's very excited to know what's in the box, after I open up the box and show her what it is, she responds "**I didn't like it**". Can we say that she "**spoiled the moment**" by saying that? or should I say that she **ruined the moment**? 
This question comes from a doubt I had while watching a TV series episode where two people are making love to each other when one of them says "**"Shush, you're spoiling it"**" which made me wonder whether **spoil** can also be used as **ruin** in that case.

How common is it to use **spoil** that way in contrast with the word **ruin**?

Can this be said in **American English**?

Answer (score 7):

You can spoil or ruin a moment, an occasion, an event, a day, a vacation, or any event or period of time about which expectations were high. Both are very common; ruin is possibly stronger than spoil - you can intensify or modify either with words like "nearly", "almost", "completely", "totally", etc. Neither is 'better'. In American English the simple past & past participle are 'spoiled'; in British English they are 'spoilt'.

> The Nets Spoil Another “Heisman Moment” for James Harden (US sports web site)
>
> Canadiens goalie Carey Price spoiled the moment (US newspaper headline)
>
> Romantic man doesn't let being arrested spoil the moment as he gets
>   down on one knee and proposes (UK newspaper headline)
>
> There was nothing that could spoil the moment of peace and tranquillity (UK newspaper article)

A hint: I found these by using Google. I typed, in quotes like this: "spoil the moment" in the search bar, followed by either UK or US (no quotes).

The occasion of a proposal of marriage is clearly something people don't want to be spoilt:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To me, "ruined an occasion" would be more complete — a real 100% wreckage — whereas "spoiled an occasion" would connote hitting hard at the purpose or joy of the occasion but not necessarily wiping out all its value so completely.  A subtle distinction, perhaps, but sometimes useful and important. Backed up by the following research:

Ruin | Definition of Ruin by Merriam-Webster
Search domain [www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ruinhttps://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ruin](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ruinhttps://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ruin)
Ruin definition is - to damage irreparably.

Spoil | Definition of Spoil by Merriam-Webster
Search domain [www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spoilhttps://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spoil](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spoilhttps://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spoil)
Spoil definition is - to damage seriously : ruin.